# Angular: Determine the value of href in an <a> HTML element using a ternary operator

Tags: angular

Given this code:

```
<a 
class="link1 link2"
href= "mailto:{{this.employee}}?subject={{this.getMailService().template1(text).subject}}&body={{this.getMailService().template1(text).body}}"
target="_top">
    <div>
        <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" fontIcon="user"></mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{this.employee}}
    </div>
 </a>
```

I want to avoid duplicate code.

The value of `href` should change depending on the value of the variable `i`.

If `i <= 1`, the function `template1` is called, otherwise the function `template2` should be called.

I have already tried the following:

```
href= "i<=1 ? 'mailto:{{this.employee}}?subject={{this.getMailService().template1(text).subject}}&body={{this.getMailService().template1(text).body}}':'mailto:{{this.employee}}?subject={{this.getMailService().template2(text).subject}}&body={{this.getMailService().template2(text).body}}'
```

When I click on the mailTo link I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL segment: 'i'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL segment: 'i'
```

How can I implement this in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One candidate solution for a problem like this is to leverage [`ng-template`](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-template), as this allows HTML to be duplicated and configured via variables in an intuitive way. It may be overkill for a 2-option scenario, but if you intend to grow your number of mailService templates further (or support multiple variables and/or from multiple sources) this method would really shine:

```
<ng-template
  #LinkTemplate
  let-mailServiceTemplate="mailServiceTemplate">
  <a 
    class="link1 link2"
    href="mailto:{{employee}}?subject={{mailServiceTemplate.subject}}&body={{mailServiceTemplate.body}}"
    target="_top">
    <div>
      <mat-icon class="icon" aria-hidden="false" fontIcon="user"></mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div>
      {{employee}}
    </div>
  </a>
</ng-template>
```

```
<!-- Template 1 -->
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="LinkTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ mailServiceTemplate: getMailService().template1(text) }">
</ng-container>

<!-- Template 2 -->
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="LinkTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ mailServiceTemplate: getMailService().template2(text) }">
</ng-container>

<!-- Template 3 -->
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="LinkTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ mailServiceTemplate: getMailService().template3(text) }">
</ng-container>
```

---

Edit - To address your specific question with reference to the `i <= 1` condition, potential example usage options would be as follows:

Varying the `mailServiceTemplate` variable contents

```
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="LinkTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
    mailServiceTemplate: i <= 1 ? getMailService().template1(text) : getMailService().template2(text)
  }">
</ng-container>
```

Varying the whole template reference

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="i <= 1"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="LinkTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ mailServiceTemplate: getMailService().template1(text) }">
</ng-container>

<ng-container
  *ngIf="i > 1"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="LinkTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ mailServiceTemplate: getMailService().template2(text) }">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I can't tell from your code when template1, template2 or template3 is selected.

Comment: You can imagine the `<ng-container>` as being "replaced" by the content defined in the `<ng-template>`, so you could then just place it wherever you would have originally placed your `<a>` tag. I have also added a link to the docs in my answer. Hope that helps, but let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Still don't quite get it. In your code example, the variable i does not appear at all. If the variable i<=1 then template1 should be called, otherwise template2.

Comment: Good point! I have added some examples relevant to the specific question you asked regarding the variable `i`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using attribute binding of angular. In attribute binding we needs to provide a third bracket to that attribute and inside the bracket we need to bind by mentioning [attr.attribute_name]="" these way. For your problem you can do the following. In attribute binding You need not to use interpolation. Also you can direct use the variable name inspite of adding this keyword in the prefix position. For the non variable part you need to use string quotation which will be single quoted because the double quote will be used on overall value. Then for the variable part just
concatenate those with the string. Follow the reference for know in details.

reference: [Angular Attribute Binding](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)

```html
[attr.href]=" i<=1 ? 'mailto:' + employee + '?subject=' + getMailService().template1(text).subject + '&body=' + getMailService().template1(text).body:'mailto:employee?subject=' + getMailService().template2(text).subject + '&body=' + getMailService().template2(text).body"
```

Comment: if use binding -the `[` `]`- not use interpolation `{{` `}}` inside the quotes